# Kubernetes - run job after pod status is ready

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs, readinessprobe

I am basically looking for mechanics similair to init containers with a caveat, that I want it to run after pod is ready (responds to readinessProbe for instance). Are there any hooks that can be applied to readinessProbe, so that it can fire a job after first sucessfull probe?

thanks in advance

Comment: hi Lukasz, i think startup probe would be good use case would you mind checking out once and updating the status of question if found it helpful or resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can use some short lifecycle hook to pod or say container.

for example

```
lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo In postStart > /dev/termination-log"]
```

it's postStart hook so I think it will work.

But Post hook is async function so as soon as container started it will be triggered sometime may possible before the entry point of container it triggers.

**Update**

Above **postStart** runs as soon as the container is **created** not when it's **Ready**.

So I you are looking for when it become read you have to use either **startup** probe.

**Startup** probe is like Readiness & Liveness probe only but it's one time. **Startup** **probe** check for application **Readiness** once the application is Ready **liveness** **probe** takes it's place.

Read More about [startup probe](https://startupProbe:%20%20%20httpGet:%20%20%20%20%20path:%20/healthz%20%20%20%20%20port:%20liveness-port%20%20%20failureThreshold:%2030%20%20%20periodSeconds:%2010)

So from the **startup** **probe** you can invoke the **Job** or Run any type of **shell script** file it will be one time, also it's after your application sends **200** to **/healthz** **Endpoint**.

```
startupProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - bin/bash
      - -c
      - ./run-after-ready.sh
  failureThreshold: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
```

file **run-after-ready.sh** in container

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -f -s -I "http://localhost/healthz" &>/dev/null && echo OK || echo FAIL
.
. #your extra code or logic, wait, sleep you can handle now everything
.
```

You can add more checks or conditions **shell script** if the application **Ready** or **some API** as per need.

Comment: yes I read about it. Unfortunately the service I want to monitor does some initial logic and is (business-wise) available after a minute or so. PostStart is too early. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you have kubernetes version >= 1.16, you can use aStartupProbe

Comment: In my experience, `postStart` is always executed _before_ the pod is ready.

Comment: yes you are right, mixer of startup probe and readiness probe also could be helpful. updated the answer thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are anything in vanilla k8s that can achieve this right now. However there are 2 options to go about this:

1. If it is fine to retry the initialization task multiple times until it succeed then I would just start the task as a job at the same time as the pod you want to initialize. This is the easiest option but might be a bit slow though because of exponential backoff.
2. If it is critical that the initialization task only run after the pod is ready or if you want the task to not waste time failing and backoff a few times, then you should still run that task as a job but this time have it watch the pod in question using k8s api and execute the task as soon as the pod becomes ready.